# Why corners (radius) cannot be different?

Tags: android

I'm trying to:

```
<corners 
 android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
 android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
 android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
```

No corners-radius.

```
<corners 
 android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
 android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
 android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
```

All corners-radius == 10dp.

Is it possible & how to specify corners: 10dp (lefttop) 10dp (righttop) 0 0 (bottom)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<corners android:radius="1dp"
  android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
  android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
```

try the above code it set the topleft and topright corner to 5 DP

Answer (score 4):

In Android developers http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Says this NOTE: Every corner must (initially) be provided a corner radius greater than 1, or else no corners are rounded. If you want specific corners to not be rounded, a work-around is to use android:radius to set a default corner radius greater than 1, but then override each and every corner with the values you really want, providing zero ("0dp") where you don't want rounded corners.

If you execute your code it will look fine even with the preview warning, I think it's a bug or somthing like that. This is what I wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/brown_light"/>
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:topRightRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
            />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my actual drawable (shape) XML file. And yes, it is possible to have different dimensions like your requirement. Here is the XML code:

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#696969"
    android:endColor="#a2a2a2"
    android:angle="90"  >
</gradient>

<padding
    android:left="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp"    >
</padding>

<corners
    android:radius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" >
</corners>
```

Comment: Well, the code above has worked on all versions so far. Tested right from 2.1 to 4.0.3. Mobiles and Tablets.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, the graphics preview reports: "Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect."

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#000000" />

            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="8dp">  <!-- the distance to top -->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```